# jQuery and AJAX. POST only gives NULL

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I'm doing this in Cloud9.

My plan is to make an image gallery.

On first page:

- there is few pictures, which represent different "categories".
- By clicking one those, you will be moved to the next page of albums from the chosen category.
- And by clicking an album, you will be shown the pictures within that album.

On the first page, I have made couple of categories. The following code should activate, when you click one of the pictures. The code triggers, and the jQuery moves to the next page.

Problem is, AJAX sends the id, but it never reaches the other page. The sent id is string, and it contains right word.

However, the other page, which catches the POST, won't receive it: type of the variable remains as NULL, and it contains nothing.

Code of the first page(mainpage.php):

```
        $(document).ready(function(){
            getContent("mainpage.php");
        });

        function getContent($sivu){
             var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
             xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
                 if (xhttp.readyState == 4 && xhttp.status == 200) {
                     document.getElementById("kuvaa").innerHTML = xhttp.responseText;
                 }
             }
             xhttp.open("GET", $sivu, true);
             xhttp.send();
        }  


         $(document).on("click", ".picture", function(){

               var pictureId = $(this).attr("name");
               //window.alert(jQuery.type(pictureId)); //type is string
               //window.alert(pictureId); // content is what it should be

               var request = $.ajax({
                   url: 'folders.php',
                   type: 'POST',
                   data: {
                       'idd': pictureId
                   },

                   success : function() {
                      getContent("folders.php")  
                   },
                   error : function(err) {
                       // in case of error
                       console.log(err);
                       alert('error');
                    },
                    dataType: "html"
                });
            });
```

Variable on the second page (folders.php), which won't get anything:

```
    $picId = $_POST["idd"];
```

The first page still reads the folders.php right (which means it succeed sending the POST, as success is mandatory for the getContent to be run).

Any ideas are welcome.

EDIT, working solution:

When you click picture:

```
            $(document).on("click", ".picture", function(){
                var pictureId = $(this).attr("name");
                getNewContent(pictureId);

            });
```

And that goes to this:

```
            function getNewContent($idd){
                var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
                xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
                    if (xhttp.readyState == 4 && xhttp.status == 200) {
                        document.getElementById("kuvaa").innerHTML = xhttp.responseText;
                    }
                }
            xhttp.open("GET", "/folders.php?idd="+$idd, true);
            xhttp.send();
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend you to pass the parameter from page to other throught query string, you can catch the value with Javascript if your page does not require information of backend, if not, you can get the value based on Hachachin's answer .

```
/phpscript.php?idd=151
```

with this script you can get the idd from query string

```
function getParameterByName(name, url) {
    if (!url) url = window.location.href;
    name = name.replace(/[\[\]]/g, "\\$&");
    var regex = new RegExp("[?&]" + name + "(=([^&#]*)|&|#|$)", "i"),
        results = regex.exec(url);
    if (!results) return null;
    if (!results[2]) return '';
    return decodeURIComponent(results[2].replace(/\+/g, " "));
}

var id = getParameterByName('idd');
```

Answer (score 0):

You're using the wrong dataType.

```
var settings = {
                    type: "POST",
                    dataType : "json"
                    beforeSend: function () {
                        self.enable(false);
                    }
                }; 

$.ajax(settings).done(function (data, textStatus, jqXHR){})
```

if you need to pass large objects to your service layer for a read operation, you might have to use a POST since GET has a size limit.

Answer (score 0):

I guess your page php doesn't work like that until you have it in a server.
folders.php you should move it into wampserver. I supposed it would be something like C:\Wamp\www\Folder\folder.php
So your url would be

```
url:'localhost/Folder/folder.php'
```

and you need to catch the data received in success.

```
success : function(data) {
     getContent(data);
},
```

I guess you gonna have some other bug

Comment: I am using Cloud9 as my environment. If that might be the reason for problems, I might be able to try it on my server. That just would require setting everything up...   Replacing my code with latter of yours did nothing.

Answer (score 0):

send id using `xhttp.open("GET",/phpscript.php?id=151, true);`, and use $_GET in the php script.

Comment: Where should I put that? The problem is somewhere in the $.ajax({}). I replaced  xhttp.open("GET", $sivu, true); with xhttp.open("GET","/phpscript.php?id=151", true); and replaced POSTs with GETs, but it just broke the code.

Comment: Was reading that pretty badly. So you are trying to say that that every time I want to read the other page, I send the right id (in your case 151) with the open command. Didn't even thought doing that so, shouldn't be awake more than 24 hours ^^ But that seems pretty efficient way to do what I want.

Comment: YES! That worked. Here is the code, as it stands now:                $(document).on("click", ".picture", function(){
                    var pictureId = $(this).attr("name");
                    getNewContent(pictureId);

Comment: function getNewContent($idd){
                    var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
                    xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
                        if (xhttp.readyState == 4 && xhttp.status == 200) {
                            document.getElementById("kuvaa").innerHTML = xhttp.responseText;
                        }
                    }
                xhttp.open("GET", "/folders.php?idd="+$idd, true);
                xhttp.send();
                } 
                    
                });